# Frame delay issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So actually I was making an animation using After Effects. The animation is exactly 3 seconds long. I've rendered it as PNG sequence, which gave me 90 images. In Photoshop I'm choosing the framerate of 30fps and when I try to make a GIF with that it's always 00:02:21 long instead of exactly 00:03:00. I realised that it happens cause of fact Photoshop is setting the frame delay of every image to 0.03 instead of 0.033(3). I tried to change frame delay of every image  manually, but it cuts every decimal point after first two. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is the GIF for?  Is it for a web page?  Note that GIF playback speeds are often dependent on the file size, download speed, device/hardware, or browser. A very small GIF may playback at the desired speed, but something larger may not.  If you want accurate playback speeds, perhaps don't use GIF as the format. A video format might be better.  Also note that video editing is generally off-topic here. Video Production Stack Exchange is better for that.

Comment: Hello. GIF is an artwork for a Steam profile and it is the only acceptable fromat besides JPG and PNG. I just realised today that Photoshop can't handle frame delays between 0.03 and 0.04 so I generated 100 PNGs but even with that, when I'm creating a GIF, it is 00:03:01 long instead of pure 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The GIF format cannot handle frame delay times in smaller increments than one hundreth of a second. It's not an issue with Photoshop, it's a limitation in the GIF format itself and it's a limitation you cannot overcome. To make a 3 second GIF you therefore need to make the frame delay divisible with 3. Both 0,03 and 0,04 should work fine for this.

However, since the GIF format was not made with animation in mind, the implementation of it is crude and you cannot expect exact results from it. How long the animation actually takes will depend on the program displaying it.

To solve your issue you can try to set the delay of one of the frames to 0,02 instead of 0,03 and this should remove one hundreth of a second from the total animation, but how well it will work will still depend on the program used to display it.

Your best option is, unfortunately, to accept that you cannot be very precise with a GIF animation.